# What is the subset D of the domain

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

What is a subset $D$ of the domain of $f$ such that $f\rvert_D$ is simultaneously one-to-one and onto the range of $f$?

The function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is given as
$$
  f(x) = \begin{cases}
    \frac{1}{q},\quad x \in \mathbb{Q} \text{ and } 
                      x = \frac{p}{q} \text{ in lowest terms} \\
    0,\quad x \notin \mathbb{Q}
  \end{cases}
$$

I think the subset of $D$ is $\mathbb{N}$ because $q$ can only be positive
because the range is $\{0\} \cup \{1/q \mid q \in \mathbb{N} \}.$

Can someone please help me on this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: I have tried to improve the readability of your question by introducing [Tex](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/).  It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question. Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{N}$ does not work, because $f(1)=f(2)=1$, so $f|_D$ is not one-to-one.  Also this restriction is not onto the range of $f$, because the range of $f|_D$ is just $\{1\}$.

There are many answers, the simplest is $$\{\sqrt{2}\}\cup\left\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$$